# Is MVC in ExtJs a one-size-fits-all solution?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

We have been using ExtJs for a long time, and now, with the advent of MVC pattern in it we are facing a critical question of whether to use it or not in the times ahead given the approach we had been following so far.

In our application, we have similar screens, like 40 similar screens for generating the reports and so on. These report screens would be having a form with buttons - PDF, CSV, EXCEL. All the buttons would be having same functionality at every screen, that is, submit the form to a url and generate the specific report.

**The approach which we had been following was to create a custom class, say reportscreen class, which extends the window class of ExtJs.**

**This custom report screen class would already have buttons with their handlers defined (given the fact that the functionality is similar for them for all the screens) and will also have a form present with a function setFormItems(). Any instance of this class would provide the items for the form using setFormItems() and the url for generating the report.**

This approach not only helps us in reducing the development effort to a great extent, but also allows even a new member of the team to use the class & create a new screen.

Now comes in MVC, the most advised pattern, and the approach shared above is definitely not as per MVC pattern. But then, do we need to really move to MVC pattern here?

Using the above approach, we are not only able to save the effort, but also have a greater control over things.

**The purpose of asking this questions is to know about the exact advantages we shall get if we implement the above scenario using MVC pattern and move away from our current approach.**

**Thus, what extra things would MVC bring to the table in the context above? And also, what would be the best way to implement such a thing in MVC pattern?**

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Closing this is a little discouraging as a particular coding approach has been shared for which advantages provided by MVC have been specifically asked.

Comment: This question will definitely be helpful to someone and shouldn't have been closed, considering it asks a clear question and its specific too.

Comment: +1 to reopen I had a similar question a while back and would have been served well with these answers.

Comment: @Geronimo: Could you share the URL of the question you are referring to if you posted it? If facing similar issue, then which way did you go for finally.

Comment: @netemp [This was the question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10237023/1062992) I refactored - doesn't sound like my code was as organized as yours however.

Comment: @Geronimo: Thanks, question did have something similar and added to us too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you need to use MVC? No. Assuming you've already got a structure that works well for you, if it's not broke, don't fix it. If you were starting a new project I'd recommend using MVC, but I wouldn't refactor a whole bunch of code for the sake of it. If you did use MVC, you would follow a similar approach. You'd have a base view class where you dynamically push on the items in the subclass. You'd have a base controller to handle all the custom events, then subclass controllers to implement custom functionality on a "per module" basis.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. As mentioned by you that we would need to have both view and controller subclass, thus, looks like that our current approach would be more effort saving for us. Also, given that the entire team is not well versed with ExtJs, so even for a new project we would prefer to stay with our approach.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to explain the advantages of using MVC to someone who had no experience with it. As someone who developed with both ExtJs 3 and 4 (with MVC), I think one of the greatest advantages of MVC is that it forces you to think right - whether you want it or not, using MVC is likely to result in code base that is more reusable and better encapsulated. But if you boys and girls are good programmers/designers, this will be the case anyway.

If you do choose to move to MVC, I believe that the main change will be in that now instead of handling user interaction within your custom class, you will have a single controller to do the same job - leaving your custom class to realize the view only. Controllers in ExtJs4 are global - meaning that the same controller may control 40 similar views. So no duplication of controllers here.

It's important to mention that even within an MVC design you will find non-MVC code. For example, I have a custom record editor which is a form - the component knows how to handle user actions and update the records accordingly (the form is not submitted as it's mostly dealing with associations). This component takes the equivalent role of both the controller and the view within an MVC design. It seems to me more than reasonable to encapsulate things this way, rather than split this to a view and a controller. But the (non-reusable) user screens are implemented using MVC. So maybe just another reason not to rush to MVC.

While I agree with Evan that if it aint broken don't fix it, had I been your development leader and given time and money is not an issue, I would actually request the gradual migration to MVC - overall I think that 3 years down the line you won't regret this decision. I would at least attempt it.

When ExtJs 4 came out I scraped 2 months of work to rewrite from scratch a system using MVC - I don't regret this for a second now (I did at the beginning, but not for MVC - rather for the amount of bugs in the early versions of 4).

Comment: 'time and money' are always an issue :) and along with that, its also about the expertise of team, which looks to be required of greater level for using MVC. And as shared by you - "using MVC is likely to result in code base that is more reusable and better encapsulated" - we are able to achieve this already by creating our class in our approach. Also, for 'Global Controllers', not sure how robust would these prove to be, as mentioned by Evan too that we would need to create a controller for every subclass.